# Migration Play Framework 2.5: "not found: value routes"

Tags: playframework

I had an application working fine using Play 2.4 and decided to upgrade it with Play 2.5 but I have now some problems in my Twirl templates.
When compiling, the routes package is now not found whereas it worked fine before the migration:

```
[error] /Users/myname/Projects/myprpject/app/views/account.scala.html:14: not found: value routes
```

And the code sample in my account.scala.html file:

```
<a href="@routes.Application.logout" class="thumbnail">
```

If I replace routes with controllers.routes, the compilation works fine but I don't wanna change all my views if I can avoid it. I guess this is due to a default route package or something like this that changed in the 2.5 version but can't quite figure out why.

If that can help, I have other compilation issues that appeared with the migration and are similar to this one:

```
[error] /Users/rbrodier/Projects/rzretail-bo/app/views/account.scala.html:18: could not find implicit value for parameter messages: play.api.i18n.Messages
[error] /Users/rbrodier/Projects/rzretail-bo/app/views/admin/administration/index.scala.html:15: not found: value flash
```

Not sure if that's relevant but here's my Build.scala (similar to a build.sbt file if you are used to it):

```
import com.typesafe.sbt.less.Import.LessKeys
import com.typesafe.sbt.web.SbtWeb.autoImport._
import com.typesafe.sbt.web.SbtWeb
import sbt._
import sbt.Keys._
import play.sbt.Play.autoImport._
import PlayKeys._
import com.typesafe.sbt.rjs.SbtRjs.autoImport._

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

  val appName = "myproject"
  val appVersion = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

  val appDependencies = Seq(
    javaCore, javaJdbc, javaWs, cache
    , "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.43"
    , "net.sf.opencsv" % "opencsv" % "2.3"
    , "commons-beanutils" % "commons-beanutils-core" % "1.8.3"
    , "org.apache.poi" % "poi" % "3.13"
    , "org.apache.poi" % "poi-ooxml" % "3.13"
    , "org.apache.poi" % "poi-scratchpad" % "3.13"
    , "org.apache.commons" % "commons-math3" % "3.5"
    , "commons-io" % "commons-io" % "2.5"
    , "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-core" % "1.1.3"
    , "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.1.3"
    , "org.apache.xmlgraphics" % "fop" % "2.2"
    , "org.apache.xmlgraphics" % "batik-codec" % "1.7"
    , "com.jolbox" % "bonecp" % "0.8.0.RELEASE"
    , "com.google.inject" % "guice" % "3.0"
    , "com.mailjet" % "mailjet-client" % "4.1.1"
    , "org.jsoup" % "jsoup" % "1.8.3"
  )

  val main = Project(appName, file("."))
    .enablePlugins(play.sbt.Play, play.ebean.sbt.PlayEbean, SbtWeb)
    .settings(
      sources in doc in Compile := List()
       ,scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
      , javacOptions ++= Seq("-source", "1.8", "-target", "1.8")
      , version := appVersion
      , libraryDependencies ++= appDependencies
      , includeFilter in (Assets, LessKeys.less) := "*.less"
      , excludeFilter in (Assets, LessKeys.less) := "_*.less"
      , LessKeys.compress := true
      , pipelineStages := Seq(rjs)
    )

}
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

So this should be a comment, but I don't have enough rep. It looks like maybe your import locations are messed up.

Maybe this will help: 
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Migration25#Routes-generated-with-InjectedRoutesGenerator

to quote:

If you’re using Build.scala instead of build.sbt you will need to import the routesGenerator settings key:

```
import play.sbt.routes.RoutesCompiler.autoImport._
```

hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. I had already tried that but it didn't fix the problem. I have other Play imports that are not recognized (Messages for instance) so I think the problem is more global that linked to the routes specifically.